# How to create query based on the active user data using firestore flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project where I want to list all the users that have the same job that the logged in user. Job is a required field of every document.

So fist, I have to get the job of the active user from Firestore and then create a query filtering all users with that same job.

I have this:

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .where("job", isEqualTo: ?ACTIVE_USER_JOB?)
      .snapshots();
```

Can you guys help me please??
What should I put replacing ?ACTIVE_USER_JOB? ???

My database:
[Firebase database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJvtJ.png)

Comment: Have you tried `print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid);` to get current user's UID as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#get_a_users_profile)? Also where is the job stored? Is there any "jobs" collection? Please share a screenshot of your database.

Comment: I think you're missing a step; if you want to get all users that have the same job as the logged in user, you need to read in the logged in users job FIRST, and then query for the other users with a matching job. Or... am I misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I want to get all users that have the same job as the logged in user. So how can I read the logged in user's job first and then use the obtained result to find the rest of the users with the same job??

Comment: Hey Rene. Have you tried Jay's suggestion?

Comment: There are quite a few guides and tutorials available on the internet. In fact, Firebase has a whole section devoted to how to get started reading data. Check out [Get Data With Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart) and in the flutter sections of you'll find example code of how to read data, in your case like the logged in users job.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will have a check.